# Firebase performance doubts with big data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some doubts about the best approaches and performance with firebase 3.x

My question might be stupid but I am relative new to this and need to understand this better.

If I have for example a Firebase object with thousands or even millions of entries, with for example user comments and I do a simple:

```
$scope.user_comments = $firebaseArray(ref.child('user_comments'));
```

What happens actually? Do I get transferred the entire data already to my browser in this case or is this more like an open DB connection and I get only the data transferred which I would call later like for example from only one user_id in this case?

What I mean is if this is more like for example in MySQL that I connect to the DB but did not send the data back to my browser until I select a bunch of data or is the simple command

```
$scope.user_comments = $firebaseArray(ref.child('user_comments'));
```

already transferring the entire object to my browser and local memory.

Sorry if this is somehow a stupid question but I wonder what I do best with big object structures and how I distribute them later to make sure I dont transfer unneeded data nonstop.

thanks for some input on this in advance.

Comment: You have to implement pagination by yourself.

Comment: which means that always the entire json is transferred otherwise?